# Control compiz zoom from the command line

Tags: command-line, compiz, zooming

I'm downstairs on my phone trying to VNC into my desktop upstairs but earlier today, I zoomed in with compiz on one of my screens so it makes using that screen over VNC almost impossible.

Now I could go upstairs... But I'm lazy!

Does anybody know a way to turn off zoom via the command line?

Comment: The Windows Key and scroll with your mouse can zoom in and out of your screen.

Comment: My phone has a very limited keyset (no super key) and there's no mouse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What a brilliant question! :-)

This is what you want:

```
xdotool keydown Super && for i in $(seq 0 30); do xdotool click 5; done && xdotool keyup Super
```

you probalby need to `sudo apt-get install xdotool`.

Answer (score 12):

You can control Compiz via [DBus](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus), and there is even a [helper python script](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus#Dbus_Helper_Script) to make it easier.

Example usage of the `compiz-send.py` script:

```
hello@world:~$ python compiz-send.py ezoom zoom_out_key
```

This will zoom out if you are using the *Enhanced Zoom Desktop* plugin.

[More Examples.](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus#Examples-1)